# How to reinforce brick pavers driveway edge?

Tags: landscaping, pavers

My wife wants to do "dry creek" style landscaping next to our driveway, which is built with brick pavers. Right now our lawn comes right up to the edge of pavers, and there's no edging.

I'm afraid that excavating topsoil right next to the edge of the driveway will allow edge bricks to drift away, and even if I add an edging (those plastic strips held in place with metal spikes), since on top of that edging base there will be loose stones/gravel, and not compacted dirt/lawn, it will not be sufficient to hold my driveway in one piece.

Is there anything I can do to reinforce that edge, or are my fears unfounded, and it's sufficient to just spike in paver edging?

Comment: I'd be devising a plan involving some amount of concrete if I didn't think the adjacent soil/whatever would hold the edge pavers in place

Comment: Edging will do nothing. You need to either leave a buffer of undisturbed soil or reinforce with concrete.

Comment: @isherwood: Reinforce in concrete how? Set the last row in concrete, or add a concrete edge, or did you mean something else?

Comment: Don't excavate any soil next to the edge of the pavers. Leave a 1' band of  existing soil there to support the edge of the pavers. Just kill the grass with herbicide there, and pile on the same gravel being used for the streambed. Presumably in the course of the streambed you would excavate some considerable amount of soil before adding gravel.

Comment: @JimStewart: I've considered this, but I'm concerned that if the stone/gravel level ends up above driveway, gravel will creep on and be on the driveway fairly quickly. I'm trying to make it flush near the driveway edge.

Comment: Pick up all the edge pavers. Dig a little trench where they were. Fill the trench with concrete. Let the concrete set. Set the edge pavers back down on a bed of mortar on the concrete. Sounds like a PITA. It is. Weigh this up against the option of trying to change your wife's mind ... Go back to step 1.

Comment: Gravel level cannot end up higher than the pavers unless you make it so. If it would, you could just rake it away into the dry streambed.

Comment: Natural streambeds usually have rounded stones gravel. If you use crushed rock, the stones will be sharp and edgy and so will lock and not move by rake.  This would be a hazard if people would fall on it. Dogs cannot run on it without injury. In my part of the world it was popular for a time to use a certain heavy metal edging to contain pavers or to delineate flower beds. This type of edging product is an injury hazard http://www.aaha.org/blog/NewStat/post/2010/11/22/606169/Lawn-edging-a-danger-to-dogs.aspx

Comment: @JimStewart: we'd definitely use "river" gravel and rounded rocks, not the crushed type, I agree that stuff is only good as a substrate.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dry mix of about 60/40 Portland cement and masonry sand or bags of playground sand. ( You may need to adjust mix) I use a drill with a stirring paddle and a 5 gallon bucket. Remove 4 or 5 rows back remove original underlayment replace with mix and replace pavers.  Spraying some water on mix right before laying pavers will help it bond faster.  Remove and replace small sections so that you keep everything in place. I would also stack the pavers I remove so that they go back into there original place. I would not use concrete because of the aggregate. Take your time and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Other options are pressure treated 2x for a depth you desire. 8",10",12".....use rebar or something to hold the boards in place, obviously longer than the boards, maybe double or triple, then you can pound them below grade but still against the boards. This solution may not last forever....but you could also build a "form" and do something similar with concrete, creating a wall, that would sit just below the brick edge. I don't think you will disturb the pavers much unless you excavate under them or have something, like a car, sitting on them when you excavate.